# Knockout-Validation Using Regular Expression to Validate a password

Tags: regex, validation, knockout.js

Ive been wracking my head trying to get Knockout validation to do for password with at least 1 letter and least 1 number. Heres the code I think came closes with but still rule always fails.

```
self.Password.extend({ pattern: { message: "Password must have at least one number and one letter " }, params: "/^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/" });
```

s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
self.Password = ko.observable().extend({
    pattern: {
        message: "Password must have at least one number and one letter",
        params: /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/            
    }
});
```